# Twilio - SMS Spanish accents

Tags: typescript, twilio, sms, nestjs

I'm trying to send SMS with Twilio, but the spanish accents are wrong, because instead of accents I'm receiving question symbols.

This is my code:

```
this.client.messages.create({
  from: '...phone',
  body: 'Bienvenido, tu código de verificación es ...',
  to: '...phone',
});
```

And this is my SMS:

[SMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FBKu.jpg)

I tried with charset utf8, ascii, latin1, ucs2, ... But I have the same results
`Buffer.from(message, 'charset')`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My first idea is that you're spamming.

My following idea says that maybe you could try using smart encoding for acute accents 
(á, í, ó, ú, é)

The documentation (https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/services/smart-encoding-char-list) says:

```
U+00B4
```

is the correct unicode for the accent.

Also, i just read this which points towards Twilio Support 
(https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby/issues/170)

Comment: Thank u for your answer. I tried with the unicode accents, but the result is the same. I've already done the ticket to Twilio

Comment: Some people theorize it may be dependent on the carrier since it generally uses GSM charset. Here is an interesting wikipedia page about GSM charsets. Check this guy's answer > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48243887/gsm-encoding-for-sms-with-special-characters-twilio